# How to avoid noise in site while deploying on the website

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a site. I'm using fonts from google webfonts. These fonts look smooth and perfect on google site. But when i use the same on my site, the font look very noisy. How can i avoid this.

Comment: How do you know you've included them properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely only on your webdesign webfonts. The page looks good or not based on the combination of images, alignments, webfonts, etc.. Have you tried doing a mock-up with programs like Adobe Illustrator before you test the page on the browser?

Comment: Yes the images(for logo) of the fonts looks fine in website. But when I use the same fonts for say - title of the content, this fonts looks very noisy.

Answer (score 0):

How fonts are anti-aliased or how smooth they look is also dependant on the OS and the browser and their settings.

Quick and dirty trick is to use subtle text-shadow for anti-aliasing. E.g `p { text-shadow:0px 0px 1px rgba(32,32,32,0.25);}`.

There is also `-webkit-font-smoothing` property for WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

ive also had this and it was related to IE and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType

this fixed it for me: [jQuery Plugin : IE @font-face ClearType fix](http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/05/jquery-plugin-ie-font-face-cleartype-fix/)